# How do i know if keyframe is blank or not with actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do i know if keyframe is blank or not with actionscript 3

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a frame in a layer in Flash IDE, the one with white circle, the answer is `you can't`. Layers in AS3 are not saved. They are merely converted to depth order.

What you can find out is if `this particular frame doesn't contain any children` (when all layers are combined) as it was already mentioned using `numChildren` property. If you have any shapes, bitmaps or movieclips on stage they all will be listed as children.

But you also might have something drawn in your sprite's `graphics` object which makes it non-empty in some way. If you want to check that you have to draw it in a `BitmapData` and examine its content.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no real concept of keyframes in AS3, so I think that would be hard. You might be able to play to the frame you want to check, and see if `getChildAt(0)` throws a     `RangeError` - but that is hackish at best, and probably won't work for content that isn't movieclips.

Comment: You should check this : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#numChildren

Comment: Ah looked there but missed that. Well, the same limitations are still in effect though (only movieclips - not IDE graphics).

Comment: IDE graphics are converted to Shapes , numChildren return all DisplayObject's

Answer (score 0):

You can use numChildren getter on target clip to know how many clips is inside at moment .

EDIT: 
You can also try use getBounds or getRect functions and when Rectangle width and height are equal 0 , thats mean clip is empty.

Comment: does that works also for graphics ? (when there is graphic symbol on keyframe) ??

Comment: yes , only issue You can hit is when You draw own shapes using graphics , this wont be indexed .